# Program works fine in PyDev but gives invalid syntax in Ubuntu

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.6

This question must be quite easy but as I am new in both Ubuntu and Python, I have problems finding the solution.

I have written a program in Python using PyDev on Windows. Everything works fine and I get the output I want.
Now I am trying to run this program on Ubuntu Linux. I have installed all the necessary modules and I run from the terminal the command:

```
python home/project/bin/prog/main.py
```

It starts executing but then I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Line 128 
dict_values = {z[length_arr]:list(z[:length_arr]) for z in zip(*list_of_lists)}
```

So I guess there is a difference in the syntax between the Python version I use in Windows and the one in the Ubuntu (Python 2.6.5).

I tried to write the code like this:

```
for z in zip(*list_of_lists):
    dict_values = {z[length_arr]:list(z[:length_arr])}
```

But I think is not the same.

How can I write this part of a code so that I don't get invalid syntax? What would be an appropriate syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
dict_values = {z[length_arr]:list(z[:length_arr]) for z in zip(*list_of_lists)}
```

is a dict comprehension, which wasn't introduced until Python 2.7.  You can rewrite it using `dict` and a generator expression instead:

```
dict_values = dict((z[length_arr], list(z[:length_arr])) for z in zip(*list_of_lists))
```

which will work in both Python 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: This line works fine in PyDev but in Ubuntu it gives me an IndentationError. I just copied and pasted it in the right position.

Comment: @dimitris: I'm not sure what you mean.  Indentation is significant in Python, so you always have to indent lines appropriately, and the same way regardless of Python version.